# insert delet update xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I asked the almost the same question before also, but i have not yet been able to figure out how to solve this issue of mine.

I have been assigned a project, in which I get a .xml file, which has field like, `<TITLE>`, `<AUTHOR>`,`<ABSTRACT>`, `<COMMENT>` and the `<COMMENT>` tag comes empty in the .xml, rest all the fields are already filled.
I have to parse this xml, and generate a report of it, i have already done this.
But the problem is, that i have a dropdown box for every COMMENT field in my report, and when i make change in the drop down box it shows the change on the client page but it does not update the xml file on the sever.

How can i do that. Is there anyway to insert, delete, update xml nodes?

Kindly help me with this. 
I am using DOM to parse the xml file.

Also i read somewhere to XMLDocument class to make changes in the xml file. But if that is possible, can you please tell me about where can i find samples of xmlDocument used to make changes in xml file.

I appreciate you help.

Best
Zeeshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first place to start would be at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp).  Once you can make changes to your document e.g.:-

```
var textNode = dom.createTextNode(myText);
dom.documentElement.selectSingleChild("COMMENT").appendChild(textNode);
```

You then need the servers assistance to accept the new XML document.  You will need either a server script that accepts the XML document sent using a POST request or for the server to support PUT request to replace the original XML url.  You will need the XmlHttpRequest object to acheive that.

[XmlHttp](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) on W3Schools can give you a beginners guide to doing that.